# Different values between pandas df.size and len(df.to_dict("records"))

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why might the values between `df.size` and `len(df.to_dict("records"))` be different? I find the value of `df.size=58151429` while my `len(df.to_dict("records"))=2528323` which is quite a big difference. Why can that be?

Answer (score 3):

Size will display total number of values while len display length of Data Frame
Ex: if you have 3*2(3 rows and 2 columns)
    size will be "6", len will be "3"

Answer (score 0):

`df.size`, where `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, is equal to the number of rows multiplied by the number of columns in it ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html)).

On the other hand, `to_dict` with `orient='records'` creates a `list` containing one `dict` for each row ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)).

You can see that if you divide `58151429` by `2528323`, you get `23`, which I believe is the number of columns in your dataframe.